# How to bind a single action to multiple event listeners in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Using a windows forms ListBox, how can I bind both double-click and return key to a single action. The way I have it I just copied the same action into both `listBox1_MouseDoubleClick` and `listBox1_KeyUp`.

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void listBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox1.Text = this.listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(); // Repeated
    }

    private void listBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = this.listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(); // Repeated
        }
    }
}
```

Not really a big deal for just two events but is there a way to bind both of these listeners to the single action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since signatures of the two events' delegates are different you can't really combine event handlers, especially if you need the keyboard handler to have some additional logic, like checking which key was pressed.

But, what you can do is put the assignment into its own method and then call it from both event handlers. That way you will not be violating DRY principle and if you would ever need to extend the action you'd only need to do it in one place as well as if you would want to use this same action for some other event you'll be able to do it just by calling the method.

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void listBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        SyncListToTextBox();
    }

    private void listBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
        {
            SyncListToTextBox();
        }
    }

    private void SyncListToTextBox() 
    {
        this.textBox1.Text = this.listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could bind the two events to the same handler but it's not recommended in this case. You will actually make the code a little harder to read and your code will still be repeated. In the KeyUp event you are using the KeyEventArgs.

So, if they shared the same handler you would need something like.

```
private void CommonAction(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var keyEventArgs = e as KeyEventArgs;
  if(keyEventArgs!=null)
  {
    if(keyEventArgs.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
    {
      this.textBox1.Text = this.listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(); 
    }
  }
  else
  {
    this.textBox1.Text = this.listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(); // Still repeated
  }
}
```

I would say leave it as is now. If you need to do more things when a double click or enter key is pressed, move that logic into a separate method that the two handlers call.

```
private void ListBoxItemWasSelected(string itemString)
{
  this.textBox1.Text = itemString;
  // Do more stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your designer code!
Somewhere you should have code like
`listBox1.onDoubleClick += listBox1_MouseDoubleClick;`
All you have to do is write a method

```
private void CommonAction(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){
    this.textBox1.Text = this.listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(); 
}
```

and use this method instead:

`listBox1.onDoubleClick += CommonAction;`

Might not be accurate, but do you get the basic idea?

Comment: Seems like it could work but how can I check `if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)`? I cant pass in `KeyEventArgs` and `MouseEventArgs`?